How to send a Bearer Token from front-end to back-end
My back-end is already working ,I tested it in Postman but I don't know how to get the Bearer Token,which is in front-end;  I am using httpOnly and withCredentials.
NODE:
MiddleWare:
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/config");
const usuarioTable = require("../models/usuario");
const { promisify } = require("util");

const authMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
   const token = req.cookies["jwt"];
   if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).send();
   }
   try {
     const decode = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, 
   config.acess_token);
      const user = await usuarioTable.findOne({
         where: { id: decode.id },
      });
     if (!user || !user.id) {
         return res.status(401).send();
     }
     req.userId = user.id;
     return next();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(501).send();
}
 };
module.exports = authMiddleware;

Login Route:
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const { Usuario, Senha } = req.body;
    const expiresInSeconds = 100;
    const maxAge = expiresInSeconds * 1000;
    const usuario_find = await usuario.findOne({
       where: { Usuario: Usuario },
    });
    if (!usuario_find) {
       res.status(404).send();
    } else {
   const acess = bcrypt.compareSync(Senha, usuario_find.Senha);
   if (!acess) {
     res.status(401).send();
   }

  const acessToken = jwt.sign({ id: usuario_find.id }, config.acess_token, {
    expiresIn: expiresInSeconds,
  });
  res.cookie("jwt", acessToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: maxAge,
    secure: true,
  });
  res.status(200).send();
  }
} catch (err) {
res.status(501).send();
}
});

ANGULAR:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } 
from'../../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CategoriaService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private url: string = environment.apiUrl;

  getCategoria(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get(`${this.url}rest/getCategoria`);
  }
 }


if the access token is stored in httponly cookie, then you won't have to deal with it at all.  (the whole point of that is so that client-side JS never knows it's value)  The server would set that and it'll be sent along with any requests you make.  Does your backend expect the access token via cookie or via header value?

ok, i do not know how make the backend expect the access token, which one is better get the token via cookie or via header value?
Can you demonstrate a simple example, please

this line in the middleware:  const autorization = req.headers.authorization;  suggests that it's expecting a header value.   But your login seems to be setting an httponly cookie in the response.  There isn't really a "better" method... httponly cookie is vulnerable to CSRF, while some other storage via state, non-httponly cookie, or localstorage is vulnerable to XSS.  Since you always have to protect against XSS anyway, it may be easier to use header value.  (You won't have to implement anti-csrf token for things like sending FormData object)

right, is it possible to make a middleware that checks if the user is logged in?

sure, you can check for access token either way... cookie or header value.  Something like const token = req.cookies.access_token;  Or maybe in your case const token = req.cookies.jwt; ?  I don't work with node.js servers myself so do a little googling.

before using req.headers.authorization, i tried checking the cookie, for example
const cookie=req.cookies['jwt']
but i was getting undefined

may depend on how your frontend sends requests.  It may need to specify include credentials if made cross-site, however your cookie is set same-site strict, so it's a given that you need to be same-domain.  (that's a good thing™)  While debugging you should be aware that different localhost ports will be considered different domains.  (That won't effect the same-site part... cookies aren't segregated by port, but you might need to specify to include credentials in your JS request.)

can you provide more details, please "that'll depend on how your frontend sends requests."

You should include your frontend code and details about whether these are cross-domain requests when you get the "undefined" value for cookie.

ok, i have included in the code above, i am now verifying the cookie instead of before, i have tested and it worked on postman, but when i am in angular it havent worked, and i also remover sameSite in the login

usually when I hear it works in Postman, but not browser it's a CORS issue.  (only browser has CORS rules)  It's possible the browser is excluding credentials.

also confirm that this.url is https.

Server Side:
When you log in, the server creates a Bearer Token and stores it in an HTTP-only cookie. This means the cookie can’t be accessed by JavaScript on the client-side, which helps protect against security issues like cross-site scripting (XSS).
Client Side:
This cookie is automatically sent with each request to the server, but you can’t access it directly in your Angular code because it’s HTTP-only.

what i do not undestand, is that it works in postman correctly, but when i use in angular it does not

If it doesn’t work in the browser, probably it could be a CORS issue. Just to experiment, run the application in the browser with safe mode off.
Here’s the run command for Chrome in Windows   chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

You need an interceptor in angular to achieve this.
First create an interceptor using the CLI,
ng generate interceptor auth

Here's how the interceptor code goes for this assuming the token is stored in the local storage of the browser as 'authToken'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Retrieve the token from local storage
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('authToken');

    // Clone the request and replace the original headers with
    // headers including the authorization token
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`)
    });

    // Send the newly created request
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}

Also don't forget to add the interceptor as a provider in app.module.ts
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],

